# 3D Statue Park: U shapes

Tags: grid-deduction, three-dimensional

This is a three-dimensional Statue Park puzzle.<sup>1</sup> The five squares in the below image depict the five levels of a $4\times4\times5$ cuboid. The goal is to fit inside it the four three-dimensional pieces shown in the picture, so that the resulting space satisfies the following conditions:

- The pieces can be rotated or reflected along any axis.
- No piece can be orthogonally adjacent to another piece.
- The cells not occupied by pieces must all be orthogonally connected.
- Cells marked with a black circle must be part of a piece, and  cells marked with a white circle cannot be part of a piece.

> [image]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The Statue Park puzzle type was invented by Palmer Mebane. The original rules can be found on [his blog](https://mellowmelon.wordpress.com/statue-park/).</sub>

Comment: How do the sides fit together?

Comment: Do you mean a 4x4x5 cuboid?

Comment: Yeah, just realized it's not a cube at all. Just a second, fixing the description...

Comment: Should be fixed now? That's what I get for reusing old templates instead of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Step 1:

> The two black dots on the top layer tell us that two Us must be placed vertically, going downwards into the the puzzle.
>   [image]

Step 2:

> The two remaining black dots cannot be part of the same shape. The dot on layer 4 cannot be part of a U that is entirely on layer 4. There cannot be a dot above it. Using the left given white dot on layer 2, the only way for a U to be placed is to be parallel to the two other Us, with the given dot at the very bottom.
>
>  [image]

Step 3:

> This resolves the orientation of the left U-shape on layer 1 (as well as the right U-shape, which could have been resolved earlier using the right white dot on layer 2). The final U-shape then must be placed entirely on layer 5, and there is only one way to place it (since it cannot occupy any of column 2 except for the bottom cell).
>  [image]

Comment: Yup, this is correct.

Answer (score 14):

Deusovi beat me but here's the solution in Minecraft:

Top to Bottom:

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: That's a very creative way of answering the question +1